# how to disable a button untill all the required fields are filled

Tags: jquery

Here I have written a jquery code for disabling a button untill all the required fields are filled and here my code is working fine but its a multistep form where I am entering the value and my button is enabling if all the values are filled but if I am clicking previous button from next screen then again the button will go into in disabling  state if we enter any thing then it will be active. So how to prevent this if user navigate to previous screen then button should not be in disabling state it should be active.

**html**

```
<div>                   
    <input type="text" v-model.lazy="category" id="id_post_type">
    <input type="text" v-model="title" id="title">
    <input type="text" v-model="address" id="id_post_address">
    <button id="confirm_button_login" @click.prevent="next()" disabled="disabled">Next</button>
    
<div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#id_post_type, #title, #id_post_address').keyup(function(){
            if($("#id_post_type").val().length && $("#title").val().length && $("#id_post_address").val().length){
                    $("#confirm_button_login").prop('disabled', false);
                    $("#confirm_button_login").css("background-color", "#01ABAA");
            } else {
                    $("#confirm_button_login").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is just to run your code when the document is ready too, not just on keyup.

So you want to move it into a function you can call once when the page loads, and once on keyup.

```js
function is_form_complete() {
    if($("#id_post_type").val().length && $("#title").val().length && $("#id_post_address").val().length){
            $("#confirm_button_login").prop('disabled', false);
            $("#confirm_button_login").css("background-color", "#01ABAA");
    } else {
            $("#confirm_button_login").prop('disabled', true);
    }
};

$('#id_post_type, #title, #id_post_address').keyup(function(){
  is_form_complete()
});

$(document).ready(function (){
  is_form_complete()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>                   
  <input type="text" v-model.lazy="category" id="id_post_type">
  <input type="text" v-model="title" id="title">
  <input type="text" v-model="address" id="id_post_address">
  <button id="confirm_button_login" @click.prevent="next()" disabled="disabled">Next</button>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response james. But in my case this script is not working. Should I need to call this function in html input

Comment: @Sultan it's definately working I tested it before I posted it :). Keep your html exactly the same, delete your document.ready function, and add what I wrote. I just made it into a snippet, but it doesn't really help testing the navigation. I've tested it though, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you must check disable button on

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#id_post_type").val().length && $("#title").val().length && 
    $("#id_post_address").val().length){
        $("#confirm_button_login").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#confirm_button_login").css("background-color", "#01ABAA");
    } else {
        $("#confirm_button_login").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```